# Parent-child dimension - confused levels

Tags: mdx, olap, ssas-2008

I am running Analysis Services 2008 R2 and have come across some behavior that I really do not understand and I can't seem to get to the bottom of it. I have a dimension called Segment which is a simple Parent-child dimension where only one of the four top-level members has any children. This one member, has two children. Only leaf nodes have any values.

In the dimension I have used AttributeAllMemberName to allow "All Segments" to be used to refer to the top-level members. There are three dimensions used in the cube: Segment, Country and Year.

When I run:

```
SELECT {{Descendants([Country].[Global],, SELF_BEFORE_AFTER)}} ON ROWS, 
  {[Segment].[All Segments].children}*{[Measures].[Volume tonnes]} ON COLUMNS 
FROM [Market] 
WHERE [Year].[2012]
```

I see all members on the columns but the one node that has children has an empty column. My understanding is that "children" should show me only one level not two. If, on the other hand I run

```
SELECT {{Descendants([Country].[Global],, SELF_BEFORE_AFTER)}} ON ROWS, 
  {[Segment].[(all)].[All Segments].children}*{[Measures].[Volume tonnes]} ON COLUMNS 
FROM [Market] 
WHERE [Year].[2012]
```

I see exactly what I would expect; the four top-level children with correctly aggregated values for the one child that has its own children. No grand-children are shown. In either case the right number of rows are displayed.

The only difference between the two queries is that the "[(all)]" level has been explicitly listed in the second query. Given that the "all" member is defined as the only member of the "(all)" level set, these two queries should return the same values but they don't. I must be missing something in the dimension config, but what? Can someone point me in the right direction to fix this? I need the query to work properly without having to use "[(all)]".

To stop this post becoming too bloated, I have posted some screen-grabs of BIDS to my own website to show the configuration of the dimension. There are three attributes and the dimension itself that require configuration but I can only post two links so have linked them all in from this page: http://coolwire.co.uk/share/BIDS.html

The Hierarchy and the Ordering are related to the Key by rigid attribute-relationships.

It all looks okay to me but the problem must be in here somewhere.

Comment: Can you explain what [Global] is and how it relates to the Segment dimension? Also, what is [2012] in your where clause? Typically, you want to explicitly specify the dimension member you are using in your axis or slicer because the cube can make assumptions about which member you want.

Comment: Also, you have not specified any arguments for the descendants function other than hierarchy. "If no level or distance is specified, the default value for the level used by the function is determined by calling the Level function (<<Member>>.Level) for the specified member or by calling the Level function for each member of the specified set. If no level expression, distance or flags are specified, the function performs as if the following syntax were used:
Descendants(Member_Expression, Member_Expression.Level, SELF_BEFORE_AFTER)"
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146075.aspx

Comment: The rows are coming out okay despite the lack of arguments to the Descendants function. The problem I am seeing is on the columns where leaving out the "(all)" level from the query causes all members to be displayed rather than just the children of the top level. In addition, the roll-up isn't happening for the one top-level member that has children. When I specify the level using "[(all)]", everything is ok but "All Segments" should imply the "[(all)]" level shouldn't it? I suspect the problem is in my cube/dimension config but my other parent-child dimensions are working fine.

Comment: Post has been updated to address mmarie's comments. Thanks.

Comment: Can you post an image or copy past what your Segment dimension properties/settings are? I think you are on the right track with suspecting something in the dimension definition.

Comment: I have have added a link to the screen-grabs in my original post as requested by @mmarie but here's the link again: [screen-grabs](http://www.coolwire.co.uk/share/BIDS.html)